# Custom Cypress click() command to always return click({force: true})

Tags: javascript, automation, command, click, cypress

In most of my specs, I end up passing `{force: true}` to the `click()` command.
It becomes a pain to pass force: true to hundreds of click() commands.

A better one-time permanent solution would be to write a custom Cypress command to always `click({force: true})`

Here is how I did it

Comment: In my practice - overriding a command is dangerous in 3 ways:
1. Since you are not the author of the command - you do not know the possible side effects. 
2. If you work on a team and/or someone else needs to write tests on the same settings - they will not know you changed the default behaviour and will get problems
3. On your case for example: auto setting '{force:true}' will bypass the visibility/existence check and will make e2e test to be more flaky and unrelyable

My advice is to make a separate command like `cy.clickForceTrue()` so you have the option.

Answer (score 1):

```
// cypress/support/index.js

Cypress.Commands.add('forceClick', { prevSubject: 'element' }, element => {
  return cy.wrap(element).click({ force: true })
})
```

The above command is not chainable.
To make the above command chainable, add this command to the global Cypress Chainable interface in your `cypress/support/index.d.ts`

```
// in cypress/support/index.d.ts
// load type definitions that come with Cypress module
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    /**
     * Custom command to force click an element.
     * @example cy.get('[data-test="Login"]').forceClick()
     */
    forceClick(): Chainable<Element>
  }
}
```

Comment: Forcing every click is just lazy testing. See [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements#Forcing) for a list of what your test will no longer be doing.

Comment: @SteveZodiac not quite. You still have the option not to force click by passing `{force: false}` to `click()` . Might be lazy testing in your lazy world. In my world its called smart testing and saves a lot of time and typing effort